# Change EntityState for Entity in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I have an **unchanged** entity detached from one DomainContext and has been attached to another.

When the latter domain context submits it's changes it's trying to have the DomainService insert this unchanged entity. It's not new and it's not changed. It shouldn't be in the change set.

This enitity is around solely for displaying some of it's data. Can I change the EntityState somehow, so it doesn't try to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the EntitySet.Detach and EntitySet.Attach (instead of Remove/Add) methods, then it should treat the state as unchanged instead of new.

Answer (score 0):

To the EntitySet, your Entity is new so it will try to insert it.
I don't believe it's possible to change the state but you could always temporarily remove the Entity from the EntitySet, submit your changes and add it back.